# Playing a video selected from an onActivityResult in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-videoview

I have a button and a video view in a layout. When I click the button, the content picker should popup to select a video and then I need to be able to play that video on the video view I have in my layout.

Following is the code I tried in onActivityResult():

```
final Uri videouri = videoreturnedIntent.getData();
videoView.setVideoPath(videouri.toString());
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need edit something like this:

```
  final Uri videouri = videoreturnedIntent.getData();
videoView.setVideoPath(videouri.toString());
```

to

```
final Uri videouri =videoreturnedIntent.getData();
videoView.setVideoURI(videouri);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of complete VideoActivity. When you record it you get videouri. So you can use it directly.

```
public class VideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
    private static final String BUNDLE_URL = "url";
    private static final String BUNDLE_TITLE = "title";
    private VideoView mVideoView;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    public static Intent newIntent(Activity activity, String title, String url) {
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(activity, VideoActivity.class);
        mIntent.putExtra(BUNDLE_TITLE, title);
        mIntent.putExtra(BUNDLE_URL, url);
        return mIntent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
        try {
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            String url = bundle.getString(BUNDLE_URL);

            mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview_video);
            MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
            Uri video = Uri.parse(url);

            mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
            mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mVideoView.requestFocus();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.unknown_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVideoView.start();
    }
}
```